# Train Keras Stateful LSTM return_seq=true not learning

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

## Consider this minimal runnable example:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


max = 30
step = 0.5
n_steps = int(30/0.5)

x = np.arange(0,max,step)
x = np.cos(x)*(max-x)/max

y = np.roll(x,-1)
y[-1] = x[-1]

shape = (n_steps,1,1)
batch_shape = (1,1,1)

x = x.reshape(shape)
y = y.reshape(shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, stateful=True, batch_input_shape=batch_shape))
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, stateful=True))

model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')

for i in range(1000):
    model.reset_states()
    model.fit(x,y,nb_epoch=1, batch_size=1)
    p = model.predict(x, batch_size=1)
    plt.clf()
    plt.axis([-1,31, -1.1, 1.1])
    plt.plot(x[:, 0, 0], '*')
    plt.plot(y[:,0,0],'o')
    plt.plot(p[:,0,0],'.')
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.001)
```

---

As stated in the keras API https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/

> the last state for each sample at index i in a batch will be used as
>   initial state for the sample of index i in the following batch

So I'm using `batch_size = 1` and I'm trying to predict the next value in the decaying cos-function for each timestep. The prediction, or the red dots in the picture below should go into the green circles for the script to predict it correctly, however it doesn't converge... Have any idea to make it learn?

[image: 1]

Comment: Try to `reset_states` also before prediction.

Comment: Still not convergeing :(

Comment: So try `mae` insteas of `mse`

Comment: No difference.. Are you sure this can be fixed by simply changing hyperparameters? Because right now it's not learning anything at all.

Comment: It's weird - but I would also try `model.train_on_batch(x, y)` instead of your `model.fit`. It's beacuse the parameters of `rmsprop` are reset after each epoch.

Comment: Wow, that made the trick, it's learning now!!! Thank you :D However it will not get to zero in loss, when it approaches the target it starts go a bit "wobbly", and oscillates up and down, sometimes quite a bit. Perhaps that is a settinging in RMSprop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138126/discussion-between-marcin-mozejko-and-user1506145).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lied in a calling `model.fit` for each epoch separately. In this case `optimizer` parameters are reset what was harmful for a training process. Other thing is calling `reset_states` also before prediction - as if it wasn't called - the `states` from `fit` are starting states for prediction what also might be harmful. The final code is following:

```
for epoch in range(1000):
    model.reset_states()
    tot_loss = 0
    for batch in range(n_steps):
        batch_loss = model.train_on_batch(x[batch:batch+1], y[batch:batch+1])
        tot_loss+=batch_loss

    print "Loss: " + str(tot_loss/float(n_steps))
    model.reset_states()
    p = model.predict(x, batch_size=1)
```