# keras stateful LSTM

Tags: python, keras, lstm

Please consider this simple example

```
nb_samples = 100000
X = np.random.randn(nb_samples)
Y = X[1:]
X = X[:-1]
X = X.reshape((len(Y), 1, 1))
Y = Y.reshape((len(Y), 1))
```

So we have basically

```
Y[i] = X[i-1]
```

and the model is simply a lag operator.

I can learn this model with a stateless LSTM, but I want here to understand and apply stateful LSTMs in Keras.

So I try to learn this model with a stateful LSTM, by giving the pairs of values `(x, y)` one by one `(batch_size = 1)`

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(batch_input_shape=(1, 1, 1),
               output_dim =10,
               activation='tanh', stateful=True
          )
    )
model.add(Dense(output_dim=1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')


for epoch in range(50):
    model.fit(X_train,
              Y_train,
              nb_epoch = 1,
              verbose = 2,
              batch_size = 1,
              shuffle = False)
    model.reset_states()
```

But the model does not learn anything.

As per Marcin suggestion, I modified the training code as follows:

```
for epoch in range(10000):
    model.reset_states()
    train_loss = 0
    for i in range(Y_train.shape[0]):
        train_loss += model.train_on_batch(X_train[i:i+1],
                         Y_train[i:i+1],
                         )
    print '# epoch', epoch, '  loss ', train_loss/float(Y_train.shape[0])
```

but I am still seeing a mean loss around 1, which is the standard deviation of my randomly generated data, so the model does not seem to learn.

Am I having something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to increase the number of units? You want your network to memoize completely random pattern of length 10000 - so in fact it should be memoized completely as a sequence. `10` units might simply be not enough for this. You could also decrease the sequence length or try to check some continous function (like `sin` or polynomial). At this moment your architecture seems to be to simple for your task.

Comment: @volatile LSTM often learn running averages. The running average of `randn` will be 0. If this is your output then the learning actually succeeded. Try learning something meaningful.

Comment: @nemo : Thanks for the answers. I am not learning a random pattern of length 10000 but a pattern in which the output at t should be the input at t-1. What I hoped is that the network will learn to simply put the input x[t] in its hidden state, then at t+1, return its hidden state as output y[t+1], and replaces the hidden state by x[t+1], and do like that recursively. Obviously, I can achieve this by using a stateless LSTM with a moving window, but wanted to have the result with a stateful one

Answer (score 1):

As you may read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811746/train-keras-stateful-lstm-return-seq-true-not-learning/42813736#42813736) even though your model states are not reset due to statefulness of your network - a parameters of your optimizer are - and due to the fact that optimizers are extremely important in recurrent neural network training - resetting their states might be extremely harmful for your training. In order to prevent that try:

```
for epoch in range(50):
    model.train_on_batch(X_train,
              Y_train)
    model.reset_states()
```

A `train_on_batch` method doesn't reset your optimizer states what could make your training possible.

Comment: Thank you. I tried but does not seem to work. I updated my question to tell what I am doing nnow